# Trying to use aws-sdk from inside NodeJS AWS Lambda does timeout and not work, why?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk-js, aws-vpn

I'm trying to use [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) from NodeJS AWS Lambda where the Lambda is running inside a VPC on AWS. What I find is that when I make the AWS API call in my Lambda and then execute the Lambda it just times out with "Task timed out after 180.05 seconds", I have no result back from AWS API call.

Without the AWS API call then the Lambda works normally, of course without any AWS API result.

Why is this? Is it the case that aws-api is trying to call out to the internet and this VPC Lambda has no internet connection? What can I do to allow it to work?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm running into a similar case where a NodeJs Lambda runs fine in a default config with the VPS set to "none", but when I move it within a default or custom VPC, any call to an AWS service object will "hang" (never return a value).  Instead, the Lambda will eventually timeout.  I've confirmed the Lambda has outgoing internet access.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you lambda function is timeout after 180 sec's, so you should try to use maximum timeout limit of lambda function which is around 300 sec's previously but now it is around **15 minutes** yes it's minutes not sec's. It's depend on your requirements what timeout limit you wanna use.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/

To configure the timeout limit in nodeJS you can try the following way:

```
// maxRetries: retry count / timeout: socket timeout / connectTimeout: new connection timeout

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({

    maxRetries: 2,

    httpOptions: {

        timeout: 30000,

        connectTimeout: 5000

    }

});
```

For more information:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-retry-timeout-sdk/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I think that it shouldn't take that long, it should have have called the AWS API

Comment: You can watch in cloudWatch log's that what is basically happened in API call, is lambda timeout or API timeout is reached. so in that way you can be in better place to understand the problem.